# Is it possible to stop all streams when algebra provides?

Tags: scala, scala-cats, fs2, cats-effect

I have the following trait that returns `fs2.Stream`

```
trait Test {
    def action(arg: Int): fs2.Stream[IO, Unit]
}
```

The returned `fs2.Stream`s are infinite and therefore one should be able to stop them. Given an implementation of `trait Test` is it possible to create a `Resource[IO, Test]` that stops all streams returned by `def action(arg: Int): fs2.Stream[IO, Unit]` on release?

Comment: What do you mean with stop the stream?

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez That's a good question meaning that my original question makes no sense.

Comment: So... do you want to edit this question? or just delete it? or what are you planning?

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez Stream termination on occuring some event can be done with merging the orginal stream with a stream `Stream` emiting the only termination token with `mergeHaltBoth`. So using `Resource` here does not make any sense.

Comment: @St.Antario You mean terminating/stopping of execution flow. Not the stream itself.